# Setting a background image using setStyleSheet in Qt 5.01 in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, background-image, ubuntu-12.04

I have a C++ code that uses Qt libraries. When I run my code in Windows, with Qt 4.8 libraries and using MSVS2010 everything is fine and I see that the image that I am using is shown as a background image in a UI.
But same code in Ubuntu using Qt 5.01 does not show the background image.
The code that I have is in the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(myimage.png); background-repeat: none; background-position: center;");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Is there something different in Qt 5.01 or in Ubuntu vs. Windows?
One thing that I must mention is that for Qt 5.01 I found `QApplication` under `QtWidgets` folder but for Qt 4.8 it was under `QtGui` folder. Might this cause a problem?

Comment: They did change how they draw widgets to use OpenGL so that could have an impact, can you try it with just a solid colour instead of an image to verify that it's applying the stylesheet? That might point out where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes the background color change does work, so stylesheet is being applied.

Comment: Rules out one possibility, try a direct path to the image for the stylesheet just in case.

Comment: can you explain what is the command for direct path?

Comment: I mean `/home/username/directory/image.png`

Comment: I did and still the image is not showing. Do you have any other  suggestion? Thanks.